# ArcGIS Pro and how to use Python to calculate an output from multiple table columns

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm not sure how to work with tables in ArcGIS Pro using Python. I've done some coding in other areas but whenever I see the code snippets related to table operations my mind just goes cross-eyed. I'd like to rectify that.

I have a table with 5 columns; [GP_Min, GP_Max, Z_Min, Z_Max, ZUp_or_Down]
These relate to the dwelling units per acre for a cities general plan in a min-max setup such that for a general plan such as 'Agriculture' the GP_Min = 0 and GP_Max = 0.5. The conforming zoning would also be 'Agriculture' and has a Z_Min = 0 and Z_Max = 0.5.

However, not all 'Agriculture' general plan designations have a zoning of 'agriculture'.

What I would like to do, in layman's terms, is something like this:

If the general plan is not equal to the zoning then, if the general plan dwelling units per acre is greater than the zoning dwelling units per acre, define this as Up-Zoning, if it is less than the zoning dwelling units per acre, define this as Down-Zoning.

Any resources or guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Artwork21's suggestion to create a geodatabase table in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, then call the Field Calculator to calculate the values of your "ZUp_or_Down" field, based on an evaluation of the values in the fields.

For guidance in general on ArcPy Field Calculations, do take a look at ESRI's documentation at https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm.

For your case specifically, using the Field Calculator, please see attached code and screenshot.

**"ZUp_or_Down =":**

```
calcDensityClasses(!GP_Min!, !GP_Max!, !Z_Min!, !Z_Max!, !ZUp_or_Down!)
```

**"Code Block":**

```
def calcDensityClasses(GP_Min, GP_Max, Z_Min, Z_Max, ZUp_or_Down):
    if (GP_Min == Z_Min and GP_Max == Z_Max):
        return 'GP and Z are the same.'
    elif (GP_Min > Z_Min and GP_Max > Z_Max):
        return 'UP-ZONING'
    elif (GP_Min < Z_Min and GP_Max < Z_Max):
        return 'DOWN-ZONING'
    else:
        return 'What about this case?'
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the columns are all in one table I'd recommend adding the table into a Pro project and writing a python function within field calculator.  If you do a web search on python and field calculator you should get many q/a hits with code samples.  Also below is the field calculator help page:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/tables/fundamentals-of-field-calculations.htm

You may also use the arcpy [update cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to make calculation but that will involve more python logic such as getting the layer object.

If you edit your question and include a code attempt then I or others can further assist with the logic.